# Why descend a representation (of a finite group) over $K$ to a representation over $k$ with $k$ a subfield of $K$ is useful?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview, galois-cohomology

I heard that Schur was trying to answer the following question

*Given a representation of a finite group $G \overset{\rho}{\rightarrow} \operatorname{GL}_{n}(K)$, how to find the smallest subfield $k$ of $K $ such that there is a representation
$$\rho_{k}:G\rightarrow\operatorname{GL}_{n}(k),$$
with $\rho_{k}\otimes K \simeq \rho$?*

(Note in passing that for Galois extensions $K/k$ the obstruction to the existence of such a $\rho_{k}$ can be formulated using cocycles and coboundaries of Galois cohomology.)

**Question** Why is it important to be able to descend a representation like this? What does this tell us about representation? Does anyone have any references?

Comment: A trivial, but sometimes useful, observation is that it implies that the trace character is $k$-valued.

Comment: There are definitely applications of being able to descend all the way down to subrings of $K$, not necessarily subfields; e.g. if we can descend to $\mathcal{O}_k$ then we can reduce the representation modulo prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_k$.

Comment: And for a finite group, if you can descend to a number field you can descend to the ring of integers localized at finitely many places. In particular, you can still reduce modulo all but finitely many prime ideals.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting (in my opinion)
application is due to W. Feit, who used the Schur index (combined with Brauer's characterization of characters) to give a proof that every complex irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ is realizable over the field $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, where $G$ has exponent $n$ and $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

It is relatively easy to show that every complex representation of $G$ is realizable over some Galois extension $\mathbb{K}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, but not as straightforward to show that $\mathbb{K}$ may be chosen to be an Abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks @Geoff, but now I can ask the same question, why is this useful? By this I mean my feeling is that we have more tools working on an algebraically closed field (sorry to ask this a bit late after your answer). Do you have concrete examples where we can deduce strong information on the group G from that fact?